# Running two applications simultaneously

Tags: android, android-activity, transparent

I'm working on an application which contains a transparent screen and I need other applications such as Google Maps to run behind it, is there a way to run 2 apps simultaneously ?

Currently when I open my app all I see behind it is the menu displaying all opened apps, but can't figure out how to keep apps running behind mine.

Comment: No, not like that.  When a new Activity launches, the onPause function of the Activity behind it is called.  There chances that a paused activity will work are fairly low even if you could somehow hack it so that touches went through.  Depending on what you want you may be able to do it with a Service using the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm working on an application which contains a transparent screen and I need other applications such as Google Maps to run behind it

Given the fact that other developers write those other applications, you have no reliable way to knowing exactly what the user can see through the transparent portion of your UI. That will vary based on device, version of the other app, etc.

> Currently when I open my app all I see behind it is the menu displaying all opened apps

What is visible through your transparent portion of your UI is whatever activity happens to be behind it.

> can't figure out how to keep apps running behind mine

The decision of what other apps do is up to the developers of those other apps, not you.

> is there a way to run 2 apps simultaneously ?

You are certainly welcome to start some activity (e.g., a map), and then some time later start some other activity (e.g., the one of yours with the transparent pane). What the other app does, when you do this, is up to the developers of the other app, not you.